# Escape special characters in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to Javascript `regex` and trying to convert a `Java` based `regex` pattern into `Javascript`. But, I am facing a problem in escaping special characters in the character class. I have added backslashes but still, the problem exists.

**Code:**

```
const regexp2 = /^(?=.*[*.!@$%^&(){}[]:;<>,.?/~_+-=|\]).{6,12}$/;
```

Comment: `[]` should be `[\]`

Comment: `]` is special inside character classes. Also, `-` must be escaped or put at the start/end of the character class. So, use `/^(?=.*[*.!@$%^&(){}[\]:;<>,.?\/~_+=|-]).{6,12}$/`. `/` inside square brackets can usually be left as is, unescaped, but it is a good idea to escape it (especially if you need to test it online).

Comment: / is also a special character. Escape it like this: `\/`.